# authentication once and use db session after it to authenticate?

Tags: php, validation, session, authentication

currently i have code, to authenticate user and save the authentication username and password in db session, which gets validate on every request.

i was thinking to change the validation method to authenticate user only once and keep success authentication in db session, But dont validate user again, if he is session user and already validated.

would this new approach is safer? or should i just validate user on each request, even if its saved on session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do this:

- keep a table of username and **encrypted** passwords in your database (encrypted = at least salted & hashed)
- have your users send you the username and password, possibly hashed client-side, and ckeck it againt the hash
- check the credentials once and set something in your session which will flag the user as authenticated

You should never keep password clear text, and you should not store extra authentication data in your session tables. Even if you check them at each request, you are in fact just checking if your remote user (i.e. his cookie) provided the correct username and password the first time on your session... you can have the same exact result if you just set a variable in your session...

Comment: What would you recommend for checking active status? For example, if a user was disabled and logged in at the time of disabling, they would still have access to the system until their session ended unless you pulled the data for that user from the database and checked the status field on every request. Is that what you would recommend in this case or do you know of another way to end the users session when their status changes to inactive and they are already logged in?

Comment: Everything depends on the level of control you need to have. Most of the times, session expiration is enough. However if your needs are different, of course you can retrieve and check the user at each request. If you have an initialization code, that is the right place to check whether the user is still enabled and such...

Answer (score 0):

Rather than store the authentication state of a user in a DB, use a cookie. Use an obscure variable name which store an encrypted unix timestamp of authentication to make things more difficult for an observer to understand. This has the advantage that, if you use a reversible cypher, a simple calculation is required to check for expiry of the session.

This also removes a whole bunch of DB accesses which would cause slow down.

As @Palantir mentioned, store passwords in an encrypted fashion in the database. When a user supplies a password, perform the same encryption and compare the stored version